# How can I extract text from between two xml tags using sed

Tags: xml, linux, sed

I have the following output from curl:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><ns3:getNodesResponse xmlns:ns3='http://node.sdk.nms.ov.hp.com/'><return><item><created>2016-01-12T18:04:44.617Z</created><deviceCategory>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.other</deviceCategory><deviceDescription>No Device Profile found for this device. The assigned SNMP OID is the top of a Opto 22 subtree</deviceDescription><deviceFamily>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.opengear</deviceFamily><deviceModel>Opengear Generic</deviceModel><deviceVendor>com.hp.ov.nms.devices.opengear</deviceVendor><discoveryState>DISCOVERY_COMPLETED</discoveryState><endNode>false</endNode><>false</IPv4Router><id>330742910324</id><lanSwitch>false</><longName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</longName><managementMode>MANAGED</managementMode><modified>2016-06-21T19:46:38.837Z</modified><name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</name><notes></notes><snmpSupported>true</snmpSupported><snmpVersion>V2C</snmpVersion><status>NORMAL</status><systemContact>Unspecified (Management Console -&gt; Alerts &amp; Logging -&gt; SNMP)</systemContact><systemDescription>Linux xxxxx 3.10.0-uc0 #1 Mon Dec 21 16:21:01 EST 2015 armv4tl</systemDescription><systemLocation>Unspecified (Management Console -&gt; Alerts &amp; Logging -&gt; SNMP)</systemLocation><systemName>xxxxxx</systemName><systemObjectId>.1.3.6.1.4.1.25049.1.81</systemObjectId><uuid>e3a77c1c-ab82-4dfb-b7bf-78e1dadef888</uuid></item></return></ns3:getNodesResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

How can I retrieve the text between `<id>` and `</id>`? I tried using:

```
sed -e 's/<id>\(.*\)<\/id>/\1/'
```

but that results in the entire block of text being printed out instead of just the part between  and <\id>.

I don't have the ability to install programs on this box so I'd rather not go through the hassle of manually compiling xmlstarlet, etc, just to extract this one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for explaining why you are not doing the obvious with the correct tools

```
sed -e 's/.*<id>\(.*\)<\/id>.*/\1/'
```

match what you don't want too   (untested)

Comment: thanks! I had originally been using a python suds library which was working very well for this purpose, but I was unfortunately not able to get it working properly on this particular machine